# Whats the word for the supposed content of an inventory?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume I have a stock of sorts and I have a list of stuff that is *supposed* to be in there.

The sentence I have in mind is:

> compare the actual with the [nominal inventory]

The words in brackets indicate the word that I'm looking for.

Comment: Expected or nominal I would be inclined to stick with, but I would like to see other peoples proposed terms, I'm sure one will be better

Comment: You can call the actual stock: "on-hand{s}" - (what you actually have 'on hand'} and cross-check it with your "list of inventory" or, "inventory list".

Comment: is than an official logistics term? when someone gave me something called an "inventory list", I would assume it was a list stuff he has...

Comment: Actual versus nominal makes it very clear. Those two terms are often set beside each other.  The nominal inventory is what the records show; the actual, what a physical check reveals.  If you don't like "nominal", then *recorded* might do. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(recorded+inventory)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28recorded%20inventory%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In the context of a shipment of stock, a "waybill" is the master sheet for inventory, origin, destination, weight, etc. (http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/waybill.html)

Comment: Like @TimRomano and "recorded," "inventory of record" is a phrase that came to mind.

Comment: Compare what's on the shelf with what's in the book.

Comment: okay, so if nominal is understood correctly i'll probably go with that. many non-experts and non-native-speakers will read this. thank you guys.

Comment: I would use *Expected*

Comment: i think "expected" might sound too mundane for my purposes :)

Comment: @BootstrapBill "Expected" is too mundane?  How exciting _is_ this spreadsheet of yours?  What's it a list of, sexy exploding dragon eggs?

Answer (score 1):

Planned Inventory

This term was given to me by a Supply Chain analyst.  It is typically seen in materials management (i.e. inventory) reports comparing the "on hand"or actual stock against the expected quantities.

Comment: thank you very much, although this is an older thread, it is still relevant for me.

Answer (score 0):

projected

expected

supposed

intended

predicted

Answer (score 0):

Perfect or Ideal seem like plausible answers

Perfect
: having no mistakes or flaws
: completely correct or accurate
: having all the qualities you want in that kind of person, situation, etc.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfect